# How to make 2 columns with 1 absolute fixed in right side

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to do same page as http://music.yandex.ru?
It have 2 columns. One with container and another fixed in right side. what framework better for it ? I am absolute noob in css.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [tour]. You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask], and how to create a [mcve]. Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: no framework would be needed to position items with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.right {
  float: right; 
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding:10px;
}
.main {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet meatloaf pig meatball andouille short loin. Tail burgdoggen ribeye andouille leberkas, capicola alcatra fatback tongue tri-tip. Bresaola drumstick short ribs, kielbasa alcatra porchetta sirloin tail beef ribs jowl shoulder tongue
      andouille t-bone. Turkey chuck tail filet mignon pig brisket, jowl ribeye swine ground round shoulder. Ground round kielbasa brisket bresaola turducken bacon rump alcatra landjaeger short loin prosciutto kevin pork belly andouille pastrami.
    </p>
    <p>
      Pig rump shankle salami meatball tongue pork loin alcatra sausage shank. Kielbasa short ribs sirloin ground round cupim. Filet mignon sirloin meatball tenderloin tail shank. Shank ham hock tri-tip pork shankle sausage venison burgdoggen ground round.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet frankfurter meatball shankle corned beef short loin pork belly. Ham doner beef t-bone. Burgdoggen ham hock andouille shank boudin. Strip steak chicken doner turkey shoulder sirloin. Strip steak meatloaf prosciutto, salami sausage
      swine pork loin drumstick. Chicken strip steak chuck beef, tail salami frankfurter shoulder short ribs ribeye.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx man for help! i add something to your answer and get what i want! ( i add another "div" with position "fixed" in div with class=right. )